# The elegant expression in terms of gcd and lcm - algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Given three positive integer numbers $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$, we may denote their greatest common divisor(gcd) by

$\gcd(k_i,k_j)\equiv k_{ij}$ for gcd of a two pair of number $k_i,k_j$.

$\gcd(k_1,k_2,k_3)\equiv k_{123}$ for gcd of all numbers $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$.

We also denote least common multiplier (lcm)

lcm$(k_i,k_j)\equiv K_{ij}$ for lcm of a two pair of number $k_i,k_j$.

lcm$(k_1,k_2,k_3)\equiv K_{123}$ for lcm of all numbers $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$.

> **Q1: Can one express $$\gcd(k_1 k_2,k_2 k_3,k_3 k_1)$$ in terms of $k_i$, $k_{ij}$, $k_{123}$, $K_{ij}$, $K_{123}$?** (here with $i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$).

-

> **Q2: Can one express $$\gcd(k_1 k_2,k_2 k_3,k_3 k_1)$$ in terms of $k_i$, $k_{ij}$, $k_{123}$?**  without using $K_{ij}$, $K_{123}$ (here with $i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$).

See a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798626/the-elegant-expression-in-terms-of-gcd-and-lcm-algebra-2).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$
\gcd(k_1 k_2,k_2 k_3,k_3 k_1) =
\gcd(\gcd(k_1 k_2,k_2 k_3),k_3 k_1) =
\gcd(k_2 \gcd(k_1,k_3),k_3 k_1) =
\gcd(k_2 \gcd(k_1,k_3),\gcd(k_3, k_1) lcm(k_3, k_1)) =
\gcd(k_1,k_3)\gcd(k_2 ,lcm(k_3, k_1)) =
k_{13}\gcd(k_2, K_{13})
$

but that's as far as I've gone.